# d3js (v4) canvas force layout with text on nodes

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a pretty basic question. I am trying to reproduce https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048 but I simply want to add some text on each node.
I could do this with svg but I would like to use the canvas version for efficient rendering.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to modify the `drawNode` function as follows:

```
function drawNode(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillText(d.name, d.x+10, d.y+3);
}
```

`context.fillText()` allows to add text on a canvas.